# How to display a matlab table in a Matlab App?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table, matlab-app-designer

I am building an app where the user can select some parameters and press a button "update", which trigger a table to be create. Let's say a table named A.

Now I would like to display this table in a excel like window on my app so the user can see the results of the data update. I can not find which element and how to set it up so that my table A is display in my app in a excel like window where the user could scroll up and down, left and right.

Is that something possible to do and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/choose-components-for-your-app-designer-app.html) component.

My example is based on the following [example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/254690-how-can-i-display-a-matlab-table-in-a-figure), which displays MATLAB table in a [uitable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) (user interface table component).

- You can start by adding a table to the application main figure in App Designer design view.
  You can also add the update button in design view.
- Add a private property to the app class for storing the table data (I named it `T`):

  ```
  properties (Access = private)
      T % Table
  end
  ```
- You may initialize table `T` in the `startupFcn` like in the following example:

  ```
  % Code that executes after component creation
  function startupFcn(app)
      LastName = {'Smith'; 'Johnson'; 'Williams'; 'Jones'; 'Brown'};
      Age = [38; 43; 38; 40; 49];
      Height = [71; 69; 64; 67; 64];
      Weight = [176; 163; 131; 133; 119];
      app.T = table(Age, Height, Weight, 'RowNames', LastName);
  end
  ```
- In the button pushed callback, you can update the table like in the following example:

  ```
  % Button pushed function: UpdateButton
  function UpdateButtonPushed(app, event)
      app.UITable.Data = app.T{:,:};
      app.UITable.ColumnName = app.T.Properties.VariableNames;
      app.UITable.RowName = app.T.Properties.RowNames;
  end
  ```

Here is how the user interface looks like (after pressing update button):

[image]

---

Here is the complete code (include automatically generated code):

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure      matlab.ui.Figure
        UITable       matlab.ui.control.Table
        UpdateButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
    end


    properties (Access = public)
        children = app1.empty % Description
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        T % Table
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            LastName = {'Smith'; 'Johnson'; 'Williams'; 'Jones'; 'Brown'};
            Age = [38; 43; 38; 40; 49];
            Height = [71; 69; 64; 67; 64];
            Weight = [176; 163; 131; 133; 119];
            app.T = table(Age, Height, Weight, 'RowNames', LastName);
        end

        % Button pushed function: UpdateButton
        function UpdateButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.UITable.Data = app.T{:,:};
            app.UITable.ColumnName = app.T.Properties.VariableNames;
            app.UITable.RowName = app.T.Properties.RowNames;
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 322 233];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create UITable
            app.UITable = uitable(app.UIFigure);
            app.UITable.ColumnName = {'Column 1'; 'Column 2'; 'Column 3'; 'Column 4'};
            app.UITable.RowName = {};
            app.UITable.Position = [36 57 251 163];

            % Create UpdateButton
            app.UpdateButton = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.UpdateButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @UpdateButtonPushed, true);
            app.UpdateButton.Position = [36 14 100 22];
            app.UpdateButton.Text = 'Update';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

You can copy an paste the code to `app1.m` file, just to see how it works (without using App Designer).

Comment: Thx Rotem. That would have worked fine but my table contains not only double type but also cell, datetime and logical data. I therefore get the following error:           Error using Screening_Tool/UpdateButton_3Pushed (line 52)
Unable to concatenate the table variables 'AS_OF_DATE_CONSTITUENTDATA' and 'TICKER', because
their types are datetime and cell.
 
Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.controller.ComponentController/executeUserCallback (line 335)
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.

Comment: There is no automatic solution, you will have to solve it by code! In case Table component is not suitable, you can use Grid Layout (and place Tables / Labels / Text Areas / List Boxes... inside each cell of the grid).

Comment: I have found a way around which I have posted as answer.

Comment: All you had to do is replacing `app.UITable.Data = app.T{:,:}` with `app.UITable.Data = app.T`. Nice...

Answer (score 1):

I actually have found a satisfactory answer, which builds on the answer of Rotem above:

In the button pushed callback, simply add:

```
% Button pushed function: UpdateButton
function UpdateButtonPushed(app, event)
    app.UITable.Data = app.T;
    app.UITable.ColumnName = app.T.Properties.VariableNames;
end
```

This works fine for multiple data type. (i actually did not display the rowName property as I do not have any in this case).